# General way to factor $ax^2 + bx$ into $($some expression$)^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a general way to factor $ax^2 + bx$ into $($some expression$)^2$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants?

The reason I am asking is to understand how the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ax^2+bx}\ dx$ is turned into the form $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\ du$ which is an important step in solving it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\displaystyle ax^2+bx=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x\right)=a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a}x+\frac{b^2}{4a^2}\right)-\frac{b^2}{4a}=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}$.

Then, $$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax^2+bx}\,dx$$ $$\displaystyle=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\,dx$$
 $$\displaystyle=e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{a(x+\frac{b}{2a})^2}\,dx$$

We now make the assumption $a$ is negative.
$$\displaystyle =e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{ax^2}\,dx = e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{(-a)(-x^2)}\,dx\frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{-a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{-a}e^{(\sqrt{ -a} \,x)^2}\,dx$$

$$\displaystyle =\frac{e^{-\frac{b^2}{4a}}}{\sqrt{-a}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx$$

Comment: This is it! Thanks

Comment: @Mason yes, there was. my bad! thanks for catching it

Comment: oh my! @Mason now THAT is a real blunder on my part!

Comment: @Mason thank you so much for pointing out these careless errors, i'll make sure to pay more attention next time

Comment: @Mason yeah, i know that it only converges for e^(-x^2), but i'll leave it to Sam to factor in the negative

Comment: @Mason i'll just add another comment in my answer

Comment: Thank you! I am aware that it should be a negative sign. Just fixed it.

Comment: that's a bruh moment! @Sam let me alter my answer a little

Comment: okay, i fixed it!

Comment: Saketh you the real MVP

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray*}
ax^2+bx= a \left( x+ \frac{b}{2a} \right)^2 - \frac{b^2}{4a}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: i think it might be -b^2/4a, not -b^2/4a^2

Comment: I agree with Saketh